# How to find orientation of an image in scene with Flann Feature Matching in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, flann

So, I was able to get matches in feature points in two images, one query image and other scene image like:

```
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.match(des1,des2)
```

Now, when I have the matched, how do I know how the query image is oriented in the scene image. Can I know the angle or the scale based on these matches?

I see the `distance` property on the match - but I don't understand how we can use that to find orientation.

Comment: The distance property of the match is the descriptor distance telling how much alike two matching descriptors are. For finding out the angle and scale I would suggest to use the corresponding key points in image coordinates, have a look at: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html. The resulting 3x3 homography matrix M contains the 2D image coordinate transform for query to scene (or vice versa) key points. I think it may be further decomposed in 2D (?) rotation, scale and translation if there is no perspective projection.

Comment: Homography - that's the term I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The distance is the distance between points in the "descriptor vector space". This is not a "X,Y" distance.

Remind of the process :

- find keypoints in both pictures
- Estimate "matches" = distance between keyoints, compared by pairs
- Remove bad matches (ratio, crosscheck ...)
- Use an Homography calculation to estimate the transformation operated between both pictures (translation, rotation ...)
- If needed, filter the homography = "This transformation matrix does/does not look good".

  ```
  def ransac_filter(matches, pic1, pic2):
  MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
  good = []
  transformation_matrix = None

  if len(matches) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
      src_pts = np.float32([pic1.key_points[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
      dst_pts = np.float32([pic2.key_points[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

      # Find the transformation between points
      transformation_matrix, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

      # Get a mask list for matches = A list that says "This match is an in/out-lier"
      matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

      # Filter the matches list thanks to the mask
      for i, element in enumerate(matchesMask):
          if element == 1:
              good.append(matches[i])

      pic1.transformation_matrix = transformation_matrix
      pic1.matchesMask = matchesMask

  else:
      logger = logging.getLogger()
      logger.info("not enough matches")

  return good, transformation_matrix
  ```

Somewhat inspired from : 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html